# Secondary sorting of a column using will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

```
Rails 6
will_paginate
```

In my model, I have the following:

```
def index
  @books = Book.all.paginate page: params[:page], per_page: params[:per_page]
end
```

which is going to give me an array of objects, each with the following attributes:

```
name
author_id
```

So, in my view, I can do the following:

```
th= sortable "name", "Name"
th= sortable "author_id", "Author ID"
```

But what I really want to do, is show the Author Name, which I can get from the book object, as follows:

```
book.author.name
```

As book belongs to author

How do Have a column in the table, with the author's name, and make that column sortable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried something like this?

controllers/books_controller.rb

```rb
  def index
    books_with_author = Book.all.map { |book|
      book.attributes.merge(author_name: book.author.name)
    }

    @books = books_with_author.paginate page: params[:page], per_page: params[:per_page]
  end
```

Also you can define to your model for future use

models/book.rb

```rb
def author_name
  self.author.name
end
```

Comment: I like the second suggestion